# Can I launch pgAdmin3 from command line?

Tags: bash, pgadmin

Is there a way to launch `pgAdmin3` from the Unix command line?  I installed pgAdmin from pgadmin.org but I don't know where it was installed.

I've searched my `/usr` tree for `pgadmin\*` and `pgAdmin\*` to no avail.

I've also searched for the answer on the Internet but didn't find an answer.

The pgAdmin [Command Line Parameters](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/commandline.html) doc page discusses parameters you can use to launch pgAdmin but it doesn't discuss the executable itself.

Comment: You can use the `locate` command to find it..  Provided you have `locate` installed..

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was such a command.  Looks like I'll have to build the database first.

Comment: You can use `find / -type f -name "programname" 2>/dev/null`, it does not need a database unlike locate.

Answer (score 1):

Like any program, you can launch it by calling its name:

```
pgadmin3 &
```

If it is not in one of the directories in your search path `$PATH`, you should use the complete pathname:

```
/path/to/the/program/pgadmin3 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Graphical utility is optional.

The link you are using describe only the graphical utility.

On linux you can use the **psql** command line parameters from this link:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html

This link might be also usefull.

http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/firstconnect.html#dataadmin-pggettingstarted-firstconnect

Answer (score 0):

For pgadmin4 for mac, you can find the location of psql binary.

```
sudo find / -name psql
```

In my case, I find it at:

```
/Applications/pgAdmin\ 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/
```

Then you can build symbolic link from `/usr/local/bin` the above path.

```
ln -s /Applications/pgAdmin\ 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/psql /usr/local/bin/psql
```

Then you can run `psql` anywhere in your terminal.

Comment: how does psql help in running pgadmin4?